# Is there a simple way to call a function with default arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-parameters, function-parameter

Here is a function declaration with default arguments:

```
void func(int a = 1,int b = 1,...,int x = 1)
```

How can avoid calling `func(1,1,...,2)`
when I only want to set the `x` parameter and for the rest with the previous default params?

For example, just like `func(paramx = 2, others = default)`

Comment: To acquire default arguments, you cannot provide anything after them. therefore, if you want to specify a value for `x`, you have to provide *everything* prior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this as part of the natural language. C++ only allows you to default any *remaining* arguments, and it doesn't support *named arguments* at the calling site (cf. Pascal and VBA).

An alternative is to provide a suite of overloaded functions.

Else you *could* engineer something yourself using variadic templates.

Answer (score 6):

[Bathsheba](/users/2380830) already mentioned the reason why you can not do that.

One solution to the problem could be packing all parameters to a [`struct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) or [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)(using `struct` would be more intuitive here) and change only the values what you want. (If you are allowed to do that)

Following is example code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntSet
{
    int a = 1; // set default values here
    int b = 1;
    int x = 1;
};

void func(const IntSet& all_in_one)
{
    // code, for instance 
    std::cout << all_in_one.a << " " << all_in_one.b << " " << all_in_one.x << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    IntSet abx;
    func(abx);  // now you have all default values from the struct initialization

    abx.x = 2;
    func(abx); // now you have x = 2, but all other has default values

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
```

Comment: C++20: `func({.x = 2});` :)